# fetch xml data from a url in Blackberry SDK 4.5

Tags: blackberry

How can i fetch xml data in blackberry SDK 4.5.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: From a file or from a Webservice ?

Answer (score 1):

See the class [Connector](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.3.0api/javax/microedition/io/Connector.html)

This way you will be able to open a file or a httpConnection to a Webservice

when the file is open use a [parser](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.3.0api/net/rim/device/api/xml/jaxp/RIMSAXParser.html) to parse the file